# Extracting Tables From Multiple Websites in R

Tags: r

I am a complete beginner in R.

I try to scrape an HTML table from a website. I have managed to do that with the use of the following:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.biznesradar.pl/notowania-historyczne/PEKABEX,1"
page <- read_html(url)
col_table = page %>% html_node("table.qTableFull") %>% 
  html_table()
```

The problem is that the table is contained on multiple URL pages and the only difference between the URLS is that they end with a different number i.e.

```
url1 <- "https://www.biznesradar.pl/notowania-historyczne/PEKABEX,1"
url2 <- "https://www.biznesradar.pl/notowania-historyczne/PEKABEX,2"
```

So I have tried to use a sequence to create multiple variables:

```
url <- paste("https://www.biznesradar.pl/notowania-historyczne/PEKABEX",seq(1,15),sep = ",")
```

However, the R stores them as a list and now I cannot feed them into the read_html function. How can I create a sequence of variables with each storing the right URL so I can feed each one of them into the read_html() function?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rvest)

scrape_function = function(url){
  read_html(url) %>%
    html_node("table.qTableFull") %>%
    html_table()
}
url <- paste("https://www.biznesradar.pl/notowania-historyczne/PEKABEX",seq(1,15),sep = ",")
col_table  = lapply(url, scrape_function)
col_table = do.call("rbind", col_table) #or dplyr::bind_rows(col_table)
```

You can create a function that will take an url and extract the table. Apply each url to the function (lapply will return a list of data.frame, with one element per url). Then bind the data.frames into one data.frame.